# how to implement paging same as safari in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I want implement paging same as safari in iphone.When user touch below button of bottom then thaey shows total pages open so user can scroll wvery page.I want to implement this type of functionality.how it possible.Please advice me for this query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement the page scrolling page have a look at using UIScrollView and UIPageControl.  Here's [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007795-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) from Apple which shows a simple implementation of this.

Basically each page is a view controller which UIScrollView manages by letting you swipe to scroll from one to the other.  Not sure if this is exactly how safari does it but it's a good start.